# ClearInterval undefined when button clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval, clearinterval

Suppose I have a few buttons and when they are clicked they trigger certain setInterval, but when I clicked on different button the previous setInterval doesn't clear or it say it is undefined.

example:

```
$("#button1").click(function () {

        var url = "xxx";
        var min = "yyy";

        getGraphCredentials3(min,url);

        var onehour = setInterval(function () {
                getGraphCredentials3(min,url);
        }, 5000);


        clearInterval(twohour);  

});


$("#button2").click(function () {

        var url = "zzz";
        var min = "uuu";

        getGraphCredentials3(min,url);

        var twohour = setInterval(function () {
                getGraphCredentials3(min,url);
        }, 5000);


        clearInterval(onehour);      
});
```

can anyone help please?

much appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The scope of the onehour and twohour functions is the function in which they're declared, so they're not visible from the other callback.

You must declare your variables in a common scope. Do this :

```
var onehour, twohour;
$("#button1").click(function () {

        var url = "xxx";
        var min = "yyy";

        getGraphCredentials3(min,url);

        onehour = setInterval(function () {
                getGraphCredentials3(min,url);
        }, 5000);


        clearInterval(twohour);  

});


$("#button2").click(function () {

        var url = "zzz";
        var min = "uuu";

        getGraphCredentials3(min,url);

        twohour = setInterval(function () {
                getGraphCredentials3(min,url);
        }, 5000);


        clearInterval(onehour);      
});
```

Comment: This doesn't work. Although it doesn't say undefined anymore, but now both setintervals running at the same time :(

Comment: ok, it looks like it works. What I did was to kept "var" both inside and outside. should be only outside. Thanks:)

Answer (score 1):

Variable onehour and twohour are local to the function. If you declare them globally, it should work fine.

Comment: This doesn't work. Although it doesn't say undefined anymore, but now both setintervals running at the same time :(